# Bootstrap 3 blurs my canvas

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, canvas, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a web app that uses canvas to diagram org charts and I've using bootstrap 2.3 without problems. Some days ago I upgraded to bootstrap 3 and I now see a blur on my canvas. Let the images talk:

[image: With Bootstrap 3] <- With Bootstrap 3

[image: Without Bootstrap 3] <- Without Bootstrap 3

I don't really want to downgrade, because it is not trivial and because I like the new version, but **how can I know where the problem is? Is there a way to tell the css applied to the canvas elements?** They are managed in backstage by a third-party, compiled js library.

Thanks!

Comment: Inspect the width and height of the canvas.  Is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: I did it in the first place and no height or width was modified. In fact, there is a diagram.redraw() method provided by the library which adjusts the canvas to a new size, but it didn't solve it so width and height is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the canvas' property `className` to see if a class is set:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas);

if (canvas.className.length > 0) alert('CSS class set');
```

or you can request properties and compare them (something like this):

```
var w = canvas.style.getPropertyValue('width')||0,
    h = canvas.style.getPropertyValue('height')||0;

if (w > 0 && w !== canvas.width) canvas.width = w;
if (h > 0 && h !== canvas.height) canvas.height = h;
```

CSS will affect the canvas if interpolation is active (default) and CSS dimension differ from canvas' actual dimension - just like it does with images.

So perhaps there is some box-sizing going on with the boot-strap active combined with padding/border or some other style which affects the size a little and therefor activates interpolation/sub-pixeling.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the interpolation because I haven't changed a thing since bootstrap 2.3. I found the answer thanks to a comment you made on a previous post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ken-abdias-software on a comment I looked into css properties and notice box-sizing applied as border-box to any tag with bootstrap 3.

I changed it and now the canvas is perfectly rendered.

```
canvas{
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Actually I mention box-sizing specifically in my answer :) Please consider an up-vote/accept.

Comment: yes you also mentioned it on that previous comment I think, and I got inspired by that haha How could I forget it. I upvoted!

Comment: why is this downvoted? I'm specifying the exact code that solved the question :/

Comment: I didn't down-vote you so I am not sure why you removed up-vote on my answer (but I down-voted you now). Neither am I sure why you removed the accept on the answer but this does not work well here on SO. We are using our time to help users such as you. You could show us *some* kudos (up-votes and accepts when problems get solved with our help doesn't cost you a thing). But it's your choice as it is our choice to help you in the future. Have a nice day.

Comment: 1. I didn't said it was you 2. I did accepted my answer because I though my comment actually shows the code that solved the problem and may help others in the future. I don't exactly know how it works on SO, I'm re-marking you anwser as accepted because it did has the root of the problem which was what I asked for. Don't take me bad!

Comment: Don't let me convince you to accept my answer if you feel yours is better. It was more why you removed the up-vote which led me to think you thought I down-voted you. Anyways, my post down-vote is locked and to remove it the answer needs to be edited (I'll edit it for you).